# I can't change the value of line_count at the right of pipe , why?

Tags: bash

I occured a problem and I can't find why does it run.
The follow codes is both used to count the line of file 'file.in' , but the first can't change the value of `$line_count`

The first code is :

```
#!/bin/bash
line_count=0
cat file.in | while read line; do 
    let ++line_count 
done 
echo $line_count
```

the second code is :

```
#!/bin/bash
line_count=0

while read line; do 
  let ++line_count
done < file.in

echo $line_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to use of pipe your first code sample is executing `while loop` in a sub-shell hence changes made in `line_count` variable get lost after sub shell exits.